# Compare two nested array then keep the smaller value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
[
    'foo' => [
        '.fr' => 15,
        '.com' => 10,
        '.de' => 20,
    ],
    'bar' => [
        '.fr' => 12,
        '.com' => 16,
        '.de' => 18,
    ],
]
```

Then I trying to compare the value of each nested array key and keep only the smaller one, to get this kind of array

```
[
    '.fr' => 12,
    '.com' => 10,
    '.de' => 18,
]
```

I tried with some foreach without success but I don't know which way to go .

Do you have some clues to do this ?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: what do you mean by "keep only the smaller one"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this.

```
foreach ($your_array as $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $key => $value) {
        $minimums[$key] = min($value, $minimums[$key] ?? PHP_INT_MAX);
    }
}
```

Basically you iterate every value of the sub-arrays and replace the value in your result array if you find a lower value for the corresponding key.

The second argument to [`min`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) is this expression: `$minimums[$key] ?? PHP_INT_MAX`, which takes the existing value of `$minimums[$key]`, using `PHP_INT_MAX` if that key isn't set yet.

Comment: Good answer. The OP would need to have PHP 7 to use ??

Comment: Thanks! That's true. I used to add disclaimers for PHP 7 stuff, but the longer it's been around the less I do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrays = [
    'foo' => [
        '.fr' => 15,
        '.com' => 10,
        '.de' => 20,
    ],
    'bar' => [
        '.fr' => 12,
        '.com' => 16,
        '.de' => 18,
    ],
];

$output = [];

foreach ($arrays as $nestedArray) {
    foreach($nestedArray as $key => $value) {
        $output[$key] = (array_key_exists($key, $output) ? min($output[$key], $value) : $value);
    }
}
```